# What does Unvarnished Transmission Mode Mean?

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I am using an ESP8266 Wifi Module and I have come across a command "AT+CIPMODE=X" which basically sets the mode of the wifi to normal mode if X=0 and Unvarnished Transmission mode when X = 1. I have googled the term and cannot come up with what it means. Please tell me what this term means and what is the difference between the two modes. For some reference:- 
https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/wiki/CIPMODE

Comment: Let your eyes wander a few lines up on that page you linked to and you'll see "Set transfer mode,normal or transparent transmission.". Whoever wrote it think's he's being clever by using obscure terminology.

Comment: Documentation found by googling for "AT+CIPMODE": http://robinsonia.com/wp/?p=360